# NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking

When i try to send a HTTP request to get JSON response like this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://data.mycitydataset.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Success");
} failure:^(NSURLRequest* req,NSHTTPURLResponse *req2, NSError *error,id mex) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}];

[operation start];
```

I got this stack on the Log:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x7bb31b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 400}
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: I have edited my post, i used to work with the same url when i used `ASIHTTPRequest`, the url is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP Status Code 400 means "Bad Request".  You're trying to access a malformed URL, or the URL that you're accessing wants to see something in the request that you're not providing.

Comment: i edited the post, please take a look, what you mean by malformed URL :)

Comment: If I try to visit http://data.mycitydataset.gov/api/views/INLINE/rows.json?method=index in a browser, I get a server not found error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happen because of not properly communicated with server while calling web service. If your continuously trying same thing you didn't get any new response. Please fallow below flow may you will succeeded.

- 1) Logout and login again (Height priority)
- 2) Reinstall app and check again  (Last priority)